# $|z_1-z_2|\le|1-z_1\overline{z_2}|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Is the following inequality true?

Let $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z_1|=1,|z_2|=1$. Then $$|z_1-z_2|\le|1-z_1\overline{z_2}|.$$ Is there a good way to try to prove(or disprove) this other than writing $z_1=a+bi$ and $z_2=c+di$ and try to see whether the inequality hold?

Comment: Square both sides and use the fact that $w\bar{w}=|w|^{2}.$ Multiply out the brackets and use the assumptions. Then note that all of your implication signs are reversible.

Comment: Since all the numbers have modulus one, they have the form $e^{i \theta_{k}}, \; k = 1, 2$.  But, also, multiply the right-hand side of your inequality by $|z_{2}|$:
$$
| z_{2} (1 - z_{1} \overline{z}_{2})| = \ldots
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
|z_1-z_2| = |z_2||z_1z_2^{-1}-1|
\end{align}
but $z_2^{-1} = \bar z_2$ since $|z_2|=1$.

Comment: Thank you :) that saved me a lot of calculations